# How to Save 'specific' line from terminal output to file?

Tags: linux, bash

I am currently using the following to save terminal outputs to file:

```
$command -someoptions >> output.txt
```

However, I am only interested in one line from the terminal output.
Is there a way to do this by changing the above expression. Or will I have to delete lines after the 'output.txt' file is formed?

For example: If my output is:

```
line 1
line 2
line 3
line 4
line 5
```

and all I want to save is:

```
line 4
```

where line 4 contains unknown information.

I am asking as I will later wish to script this command. 
Many thanks,

**Solution Found:**

I ended up using:

```
$command -someoptions | sed -n '4p' >> output.txt
```

Comment: You can pipe the output of your command into another command that will filter it, but you need to tell us what's the criterium for selecting `line 4`. Is it its position (4th line), or should we look for something special in that line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a classic simple `grep` issue.

```
$command -someoptions | grep 'line 4' >> output.txt
```

You could refine that with more pattern complexity, and might need it depending on how precisely you need to match the data.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this command:

```
$command -someoptions | grep " filter " >> output.txt
```

`filter` must be replaced by an element that distinguishes your line 4 from the other lines.